# mysql node module give me an error "require is not defined"

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to use [mysql module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction) in a node js project (node 18.12, mysql 2.18.1)

in my project I must use

> "type": "module"

in my package.json because the app is constructed with modules. for example i use this imports in the head of my app.js

```
import { createServer } from 'node:http';
import fs from 'node:fs/promises';
import { createTodo, findTodos } from './functions/storage.js';
import { index,create } from './functions/api/api.js';
```

then I add the line, like in the doc

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
```

but when I launch the app i have this error

> mysql node module "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can
> use import instead"

I have tried to change type to commonjs but get the same error in the other way, tried to change the extensions of the js file for cjs or mjs . every time same type of error.

How can I use mysql with "native" module node app ?

I'm a beginner in node so, sorry if it is a dumb question, but I can't find any answer by the web.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer [here](https://www.kindacode.com/article/node-js-how-to-use-import-and-require-in-the-same-file/#Enabling_ES_importexport)

```
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
var mysql      = require('mysql');
```

I hope this will be useful for other people ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `"type":"module"` from package.json.
From [How to fix reference error require is not defined in javascript](https://isotropic.co/how-to-fix-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. but I get an error : Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.

Comment: Which version of node are you use?

Comment: 18.12, the current one